# iPhone:Video recorder API?

Tags: iphone

I want to develop an application, which should do video recording. I think, the API's are available from iOS 4.0 SDK, not prior to that. Please correct me if i'm wrong anything and share me the API set link for this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingVideo/UsingVideo.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH3-SW47) is the link to the video recording API (which is available since iOS3.0)

Comment: Thank you. Is there any restrictions there that can work on 2G 3.0 devices onwards or 3G 3.0 devices onwards or or 3GS 3.0 devices onwards something like that? Because i don't see any third party Video recording apps are developed for 2G devices.

Comment: It sais "Starting in iOS 3.0, you can record video, with included audio, on supported devices". So, if you can update it to iOS 3.0 and if it is able to record video it should work.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm still a bit confused. What it means, supported device? All iOS 3.0 devices has camera, all iOS 3.0 based devices should support Video recording right.

Comment: All have a camera with recording ability but not all do have iOS 3.0 or higher. For example iPhones or iPhone 3G without iOS update will have a lower version. For device properties see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices

Comment: Actually, the iPhone and iPhone 3G cannot record video (on non-jailbroken devices).  Also, the iPod touch up until the 4th generation did not have a camera.

Comment: In that case, can you make a clear on this? How to implement video recorder API on non-jailbroken iPhone 3.0 2G and iPhone 3.1.2 3G device and iPhone 4.0 device?